# Debug Assertion Failed: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)

Tags: c++, debugging, matrix, assertions

I wrote a code that simulates a matrix.
this matrix has a pointer to pointer and actually its an array of linked list. i have two of those - one for the rows and the second for the column.
each array index its the matrix row/col first place, and the list is the rest number in the rox/col.

I can send the code, but its not short.

My problem is that after im doing some actions, and im trying to delete the matrix at the end - it pop me this Failed problem.
I have tryed to change my code and I found that the problem is here:

```
delete this->rowsArray;
this->rowsArray = newRowArray; ->here


delete this->colsArray;
this->colsArray = newColArray; ->here
```

rowsArray ad colsArray initilized like that:

`rowsArray = new matrixNode*[lastRowPlace+1];
colsArray = new matrixNode*[lastColPlace+1];`

same about newColsArray and row...
I hope you would be able to give me an advice cause I really dont know what to do :(

**Just forgot to say that the problem pop just at the destructor...

Comment: The problem is somewhere else.
Although `rowsArray` was correctly allocated, you changed your pointer somewhere in your code after creating `rowsArray`.  At that point, it was no longer a valid Heap Pointer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get \_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block) and/or is\_block\_type\_valid(header->\_block\_use) assertions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64418624/why-do-i-get-crtisvalidheappointerblock-and-or-is-block-type-validheader-b)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you defined a pointer such as `new T* [size]`

you should delete it with `delete[]` instead of `delete`

Comment: Did you mean **instead of** delete?